# Multiple Parameter and Input for AWS CloudFormation [SNS Topic]

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

So I have this SNS Topic I need to input from multiple email address,

```
  SendNotification:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      Subscription:
      - Endpoint:
          Ref: OperatorEMail1
        Protocol: email
      - Endpoint:
          Ref: OperatorEMail2 # I can do this indefinetely
        Protocol: email
```

I can do like above, but how I can put like comma separated input for multiple email in the stack parameter input?

```
Parameters
  OperatorEMail:
    Type: String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CommaDelimitedList` as the type for your parameter. The `!Ref` will automatically be an array as well when using this type. You can find more info in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-properties).